# React .js.jsx extension in Ruby on Rails application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, file-extension

Currently in one of project which is using React on the front-end and Ruby on Rails on the back-end I can see `.js.jsx` files for all React-related logic. It's a bit confusing for me, because I'm used for React to see only `.js` or `.jsx` file extensions.

Is there any reason why Ruby on Rails would use `.js.jsx`? I'm not into Ruby world at all, therefore it's my only one guess why it should be like that. Or it's simply a developer mistake to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People, who use `react-rails` [gem](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails) can use `.js.jsx` extension due to ability of this gem (library) to compile it to clean `js` code without external build step.
Accordingly to documentation: 


*When you name your file with myfile.js.jsx, react-rails will automatically try to transform that file. For the time being, we still require that you include the docblock at the beginning of the file. For example, this file will get transformed on request.*

```js
/** @jsx React.DOM */
React.renderComponent(<MyComponent/>, document.getElementById('example'))
```

Comment: Was really looking for this before asking this question and somehow missed it's in official React's docs... Thanks!